# IntelliJ No Run Button upon right click

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I have a series of automated java tests as part of a maven project in java. I have just switched machines from a machine where the tests run fine.

Now, when I right click on the test java class, there is no 'Run', 'Debug' options. Only the main option at the top of the window - which doesn't work either.

I have checked the Junit plug in is installed and I have Invalidated Caches and restarted.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please attach screenshot with your project sctructure and context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "edit configuration" and add run configuration for your test class.

[image]

Here is the example for JUnit but for TestNG it should look similar. You expand the combobox on the top right and choose "Edit Configuration..". Then you add JUnit/TestNG configuration and in configuration details specify the test class to run.